# How to write the JSON code for adding scroll bar to a cell in SharePoint list column?

Tags: json, sharepoint

I am not a developer but, I was trying to create a SharePoint list for online tracking of all open items in our team site. I was able to get the following code to standardize the font and font size for the columns through the below code

```
{
    "$schema":"http://columnformatting.sharepointpnp.com/columnFormattingSchema.json",
     "elmType":"div",
            "style":{
                  "font-weight":"bold",
                  "font-family":"Trebuchet MS",
                 "font-size":"13px",
                 "font-size-adjust":"0.58"
             },
             "txtContent":"@currentField"
}
```

For two columns containing significant text content, I wanted to limit the maximum row height and introduce vertical scroll bar but, am unable to understand what will be the code and how to add it to the above written code .

Any help or guidance will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Running the new code as proposed by @Thriggle did not reduce or modify the row-height of the column.

[image]

FURTHER EDIT
JSON code is being added in the List Settings section and choosing individual columns.

[image]

[image]

--

Kind Regards,

Nilotpal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add style properties to define how the cell should display.

The key additions to your style block would be `"overflow-y":"auto"` and `"max-height":"50px"` (replacing `50px` with whatever maximum height you desire).

Your updated JSON for the advanced column formatting would look something like this:

```
{
    "$schema":"http://columnformatting.sharepointpnp.com/columnFormattingSchema.json",
    "elmType":"div",
    "style":{
        "font-weight":"bold",
        "font-family":"Trebuchet MS",
        "font-size":"13px",
        "font-size-adjust":"0.58",
        "overflow-y":"auto",
        "max-height":"50px"     
    },
    "txtContent":"@currentField"
}
```

Edit for clarity, here's where you'd add that JSON:

1. On the list view, click the view selector and choose to format the current view
2. Instead of applying the formatting to the entire row, add it to the desired column.

[image: Screenshot of view formatting selector]

3. Click the link to enter "Advanced mode"
4. Paste in your JSON declarations and hit the Preview button to see if it works

[image: Screenshot of applying formatting to a column]

Alternatively, you can go to the list settings page, then to the settings for the specific column to which you want to apply the formatting, and add the JSON to its Column Formatting setting. This will apply to all views of the list instead of just to the one view.

[image]

Comment: I ran the code as shared by you but, there was no change in the row height of the list. I have also updated the question with the latest image for reference.

Comment: To be sure I understand, are you adding that JSON in the through the "Format view" selector as in the screenshots above? The JSON I provided is intended to work for a single column, not be applied to the entire row.

Comment: I was adding the code by going into List Settings and clicking on the individual column as listed under the "Columns" section.

Comment: In that case, it may be that your list is being displayed in "classic" mode instead of "modern" mode. The JSON formatting feature only works for the modern views.

Comment: you were correct. I changed my option to "New Experience" under Advanced Settings" and the changes along with the scroll-bar view immediately become visible. Thank you for the last comment.

Answer (score 0):

For all those reading this question, please note the key point of using JSON code formatting feature is that it will be available in "Modern" view of the SharePoint list. The coding shared in the ongoing conversation will provide the desired impact only if the SharePoint list is being viewed in the "modern" OR "new" experience.